# Skipping rEFInd menu after Option+Command+P+R and going straight to grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, macosx

I used <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to try and fix a sleep issue in OSX. From there I'm a little confused about what happened but I ended up in a mac recovery mode (offering to reinstall OSX), which I tried to exit out of as quickly as possible.

When it rebooted, it seems to be jumping straight to grub, which needs telling which partition to boot and I can't boot OSX (only Ubuntu).

It's as though I've changed the active partition (is that even relevant for EFI?). Can this be fixed from inside ubuntu? I have a retina display macbook, so no CD, and I'd like to fix this from inside Ubuntu ideally.

Comment: I should say that each time I end up at "grub rescue>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try booting with a [CD-R or USB flash drive image](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) of rEFInd. This should enable you to boot into OS X and re-install rEFInd there (or just re-run the relevant `bless` command from the [rEFInd OS X installation instructions](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#osx) -- see step #8).

Comment: Thanks Rod - does this imply that rEFInd has been broken and that I need to fix it? I'm unclear on what has broken exactly. Thanks for your fast responses!

Comment: My suspicion is that your firmware's boot option has been changed from rEFInd to GRUB. Under EFI (even Apple's weird EFI), you can install as many boot loaders/managers as you like, but of course the firmware will try to execute just one of them first. This value can be changed via OS X's `bless` utility or in various other ways, and my suspicion is that this has accidentally happened and needs to be undone. rEFInd on a USB flash drive is just a handy emergency tool. Re-installing rEFInd or using `bless` manually should fix the problem permanently (or until it recurs).

Comment: Following step #8: sudo bless --setBoot --folder /efi/refind --file /efi/refind/refind_x64.efi reinstated my rEFInd boot menu, thanks!

Comment: I used mcnesium's solution for getting back in however, which doesn't require a CD.

Answer (score 0):

Press Option during startup. This starts in Startup Manager, where you can select an OS X volume or other volumes to start from.

There are a number of other [key combinations](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533) that may help you to get back to the original boot menu.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: sorry, answer edited.

Comment: Holding "Option" down gave me a list of EFI options, getting me back to my original and letting me back in to OSX to follow Rod's instructions above, thanks!